# How to set the Escape key to quit a Service?

Tags: macos, applescript, services

I want to be able to hit the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key on my keyboard to stop a Service (that is comprised of a *"Run AppleScript"* action in Automator) while it is in the middle of running.

Incidentally, if one hits the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key while a Service is running, that Service will immediately stop by default. However, five seconds after you hit the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key and the Service is terminated, a dialog pops up with an error:

> The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error.

Is it possible to implement the same function, except without the error, perhaps by using AppleScript?

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow - stop applescript script from running on keypress ESC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294628/stop-applescript-script-from-running-on-keypress-esc)

Comment: Oddly enough, I just tried this again today, and I found that the Escape key does in fact now quit a Service without giving the user any error. I'm not sure if I should delete this question or not, at this point. I guess that I'll just wait and see if the error ever makes another appearance...